# How to make a cell behave like it's editable but have it read only?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecelleditor, abstracttablemodel

I have a JTable in which I want the cells to behave the way it behaves when you have the cells editable, but the cells cannot be editable, in other terms, read only. So if I double click on a cell, I should only be able to select text within the cell and copy text from that cell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> is it possible to prevent the user to make any changes?

You would need to use a custom editor:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class TableCopyEditor extends JPanel
{
    public TableCopyEditor()
    {
        String[] columnNames = {"Editable", "Non Editable"};
        Object[][] data =
        {
            {"1", "one"},
            {"2", "two"},
            {"3", "three"}
        };

        JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames);
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
        add( scrollPane );

        //  Create a non-editable editor, but still allow text selection

        Caret caret = new DefaultCaret()
        {
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e)
            {
                setVisible(true);
                setSelectionVisible(true);
            }
        };
        caret.setBlinkRate( UIManager.getInt("TextField.caretBlinkRate") );

        JTextField textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setEditable(false);
        textField.setCaret(caret);
        textField.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));

        DefaultCellEditor dce = new DefaultCellEditor( textField );
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellEditor(dce);
    }

    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Table Copy Editor");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( new TableCopyEditor() );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: +1 This works well. It even allows for partial selection... unlike my solution ;-(

Answer (score 2):

You have to override `setValue()` on the model with an empty implementation and `isCellEditable()`.

```
@Override
public void setValueAt(Object oValue, int row, int nColumn)
{
}

@Override
public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex)
{
    return true;
}
```

The `isCellEditable` tells the table which cells are allowed to be entered, and the `setValue` is called if the user enter some data. Since you overrode the function with an empty implementation, the cellwill revert to the existing value.

Comment: Thanks that worked! Though the changes are not kept, is it possible to prevent the user to make any changes?

Comment: With this solution, the changes will be visually made, but only temporarily. They won't get commited to the table's model.

Answer (score 1):

If cell selection is enabled on the table, you can Copy/Paste from the selected cell by default.

Here's a demo with a read-only JTable with cell selection on, and a JTextField to paste into:

```
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class TableCellSelectionDemo implements Runnable
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new TableCellSelectionDemo());
  }

  public void run()
  {
    String[] columnNames = {"First", "Last"};
    Object[][] data =
    {
      {"Barney", "Rubble"},
      {"Fred", "Flintstone"}
    };

    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames)
    {
      @Override
      public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column)
      {
        return false;
      }
    };

    JTable table = new JTable(model);
    table.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
    table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());

    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table);
    scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(
        JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);

    JTextField text = new JTextField(40);

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Demo");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.getContentPane().add(text, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```