# How do I allow selection of text in a cell using the right click button, but default behavior on left?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am currently modifying the behavior of a JTable. My final goal is to allow selection of text in a cell, without making the cell editable through the use of the mouse right click. Everything should remain the same on hover, or when using the left click.

I am having trouble however when trying to do this. I have messed with non-editable text fields as cell editors, carets, and etc. but I can't seem to achieve the result I want.

Some resources I looked at include:

- http://www.coderanch.com/t/332800/GUI/java/JTable-highlight-text-cell
- [Highlighting the text of a jtable cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20113920/highlighting-the-text-of-a-jtable-cell)
- [How to make a cell behave like it's editable but have it read only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17176539/how-to-make-a-cell-behave-like-its-editable-but-have-it-read-only)
- etc.

None of them have helped in my current predicament.